# Creating a list of Folders in an ItemGroup using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to build an ItemGroup in an MSBuild script which contains a list of folders directly below a given 'Root' folder.  So - in this example...

```
+ Root folder
---- Sub Folder 1
-------- Sub-Sub Folder 1
-------- Sub-Sub Folder 2
---- Sub Folder 2
---- Sub Folder 3
```

... I would want my ItemGroup to contain "Sub Folder 1", "Sub Folder 2" and "Sub Folder 3".

There may be a number of files at any point in the hierarchy, but I'm only interested in the folders.

Can anyone help!?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RootFolder>tmp</RootFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <AllFiles Include="$(RootFolder)\**\*"/>
   <OnlyDirs Include="@(AllFiles->'%(Directory)')"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

@(OnlyDirs) might contain duplicates, so you could either use the RemoveDuplicatesTask :

```
<Target Name="foo">
   <RemoveDuplicates Inputs="@(OnlyDirs)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Filtered" ItemName="UniqueDirs"/>
   </RemoveDuplicates>
</Target>
```

or use CreateItem with batching for %(AllFiles.Identity) or with msbuild 3.5:

```
<Target Name="foo">
   <ItemGroup>
      <UniqueDirs Include="%(AllFiles.Directory)"/>
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: This is really slow. If possible use the solution provided by @Stason Stangroome

Answer (score 61):

In MSBuild 4.0 this is possible:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Folders Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(&quot;$(RootFolder)&quot;))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Property Functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I added the search pattern as well:   <Folders Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(&quot;$(RootFolder)&quot;,&quot;*$(SearchPattern)*&quot;))" />

Comment: Rather than the ugly `&quot;` entities which give me headaches when trying to read the statement, you could simply use backticks (`\``) too.

Answer (score 7):

MSBuild 4.0:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <RootFolder>tmp</RootFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <AllFiles Include="$(RootFolder)\**\*"/>
    <OnlyDirs Include="@(AllFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)'->Distinct())"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Doesn't select empty directories.

Comment: This would select sub-sub folders if they have folders in them. So might work but doesn't guarantee that only the first-level subfolders are selected.

Answer (score 6):

The [MSBuild Extension pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) has a task called `FindUnder`, which returns an itemgroup of files or folders below a certain path. The following task will achieve what you want, returning an itemgroup containing Sub Folder 1, Sub Folder 2, and Sub Folder 3, but not Sub-Sub Folder 1 or Sub-Sub Folder 2:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder
    TaskAction="FindDirectories"
    Path="$(RootFolder)"
    Recursive="False">
    <Output ItemName="FoundFolders" TaskParameter="FoundItems" />
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder>
```

Answer (score 3):

[This MSDN Forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/adc728e9-e18d-4b1e-bb82-97dfd6037886/) has a custom task that deals with the empty directory case (upvoted accepted as its a v useful answer)