# How to include created database project created dacpac into a cs project

Tags: c#, msbuild, sqlproj

I have a separate database project that I’d like to build within the same solution and then reference the created dacpac. When I try adding the database project it builds fine and the dll is added to the secondary project file, but the dacpac is not.

Is there a way that I can have the dacpac copied into my main project through the msbuild? I keep on thinking that there should be a way to modify either the sqlproj file or csproj file so that the dacpac is included as one of the project outputs. My knowledge of msbuild is not extensive, I’ve not been able to figure it out.

It seems to me that I need to add the dacpac somehow to say the '@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)' item but I have not been able to figure it out. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

I tried doing something a little like what is referenced here [MSBuild - ItemGroup of all bin directories within subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422892/msbuild-itemgroup-of-all-bin-directories-within-subdirectories) by doing:

```
   <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="@(MainAssembly)" />
    <!--<DacPacs Include="%(ProjectReference.Directory)**"  />-->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DacPacs Include="%(ProjectReference.Directory)**/*bin*/*.dac" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" />
    <Message Text="DacPacs: @(DacPacs)" />
    <Message Text="Target Database: $(TargetDatabase)" />
  </Target>
```

which gives nothing for DacPacs (when the wildcard is added). Also I tried referencing one of the item groups from the sqlproj file but it comes out empty to:

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Obviously no... I have the same problem here :(

Answer (score 3):

In the project properties, you can add a pre-build event command line to get a copy of the dacpac file.

[image: Pre-build event to copy dacpac]

Or you can just add it in the csproj :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>copy "$(SolutionDir)DatabaseProject\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\DatabaseProject.dacpac" "$(ProjectDir)\DatabaseProject.dacpac"</PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will only work if the database project was built first, so you should add a dependency. Right clic on the solution and select `Project Dependencies...`, then select the main project and check that it depends on the Database project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\DatabaseProject\bin\Debug\DatabaseProject.dacpac">
      <Link>DatabaseProject.dacpac</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That would be great, but it won't work when I switch to Release configuration.

Comment: Maybe I found a solution. You can copy, a file from another configuration to Debug in DatabaseProject Post-build Event: ```if "$(Configuration)" NEQ "Debug" xcopy /y DatabaseProject.dacpac ..\Debug\```

Comment: You are right, it's currently hard coded to debug in my answer; you might be able to use a placeholder for the output path based on the current sln configuration, but I didn't get that far, I'm just hoping we can set fire to the dacpacs in our sln at some point and forget this ever happened. Shudder.

Comment: The `$(Configuration)` MSBuild macro can be used to adjust based on the build config: `<Content Include="..\DatabaseProject\bin\$(Configuration)\DatabaseProject.dacpac">`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me with a .NET 6 project which references a `.sqlproj` project using [Micrsoft.Sql.Sdk](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/tree/main/src/Microsoft.Build.Sql). Assume there are two projects: `DacpacDepender` (.NET 6 project) and `Dacpac` (SQL project).

In `DacpacDepender.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- some properties redacted for brevity -->
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Ensures build order, the DACPAC is _guaranteed_ to exist when included -->
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Dacpac\Dacpac.sqlproj">
      <!-- Companion to .sqlproj CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory=false  -->
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <!-- Suppresses a warning about this project not being compatible with SQL project -->     
      <SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>true</SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Use `$(Configuration)` to reference the DACPAC output location regardless of build configuration. -->
    <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)..\Dacpac\bin\$(Configuration)\Dacpac.dacpac" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In `Dacpac.sqlproj`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build">
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.Sql" Version="0.1.3-preview" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- some properties redacted for brevity -->
    <!-- Prevents outputting the DLL (some may need it) --> 
    <CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>false</CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>
    <CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>
    <Name>Dacpac</Name>
    <NetCoreBuild>True</NetCoreBuild>
    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Please note that `<RestorePackagesWithLockFile />` is not strictly necessary but ensures `dotnet restore --locked-mode` works, which is a nicety for reproducible builds.