# MSBuild copy files to directory path with wildcard

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a DLL that I want to copy to "\Folder1\DestinationDir" and "\Folder2\DestinationDir". I tried using a wild carded destination path:

```
"\Folder*\DestinationDir",
```

but I got an error:

```
No Destination specified for Copy.
```

Here's my XML:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ItemToCopy Include="$(OutDir)Mydll.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <DeployPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Folder*\DestinationDir" />
</ItemGroup>
<MakeDir Directories="$(DeployPath)" />
<Copy SourceFiles="@(ItemToCopy)" DestinationFolder="%(DeployPath.FullPath)" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

#### See also

> [Creating a list of Folders in an ItemGroup using MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657684/creating-a-list-of-folders-in-an-itemgroup-using-msbuild)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You build file does not work because ItemToCopy does not expand directory paths, it expands files.

So, if you want to enumerate directories, you should target the existing files in those directoris, then get directory list from the file list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ItemToCopy Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\toCopy.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DeployPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Folder*\*.*" />
        <DeployFolders Include="@(DeployPath->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)'->Distinct())" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Test">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(ItemToCopy)" DestinationFolder="%(DeployFolders.FullPath)" />
        <Message Text="Destination folder = @(DeployFolders)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Note that this would NOT work for empty directories.
Another thread discusses this problem:
[Creating a list of Folders in an ItemGroup using MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657684/creating-a-list-of-folders-in-an-itemgroup-using-msbuild)

I would recommend to specify a set of folders explicitly.
This can be done with item metadata, for example, and not rely on existing folder structure:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DeploySpecificFolders Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\toCopy.txt">
        <FolderToCopyTo>Folder1</FolderToCopyTo>
    </DeploySpecificFolders>
</ItemGroup>
...
<Message Text="Specific folders = %(DeploySpecificFolders.FullPath) will be copies to %(DeploySpecificFolders.FolderToCopyTo)" />
<Copy SourceFiles="@(DeploySpecificFolders)" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(DeploySpecificFolders.FolderToCopyTo)" />
```

Comment: This is good, however my destination directories don't have any files so they won't be included. Is there an alternative?

Comment: RE: "this would work for empty directories" - I double checked with a destination directory that contains files and one that is empty: it only worked on the one that had files. Could I be missing something? RE: "recommend to specify a set of folders explicitly" - Unfortunately that would introduce manual work as I will be adding new folders with that structure in the future.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. "This would NOT work for empty directories". I've updated the answer.

Comment: As for the "manual work" i'd prefer it this way, because the build process should be deterministic with respect to anything in output folders.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I added a link to the other thread you mentioned.

Comment: wtf.. MS, this is unbelievable. Unix had this API for 30+ years. `cp source dest`. Please, MSBuild has caught rabies and there is only one way for it to go from here..