# Copying a single file to multiple (dynamic) destinations

Tags: msbuild

I want to be able to copy a single file whose location is static to all folders inside of a specific directory using the copy task in msbuild -- the only thing is that I need that "all folders" part to be dynamic, because I don't know their names up front. I'm able to copy the file to a single directory just fine, and I can even copy to multiple directories when I specify the destination folder paths by name, but i want to be able to copy to however many folders exist in a given directory, even if those folder are empty (that's another issue I can't seem to get by). How do i copy one file (known location) to X number of folders (names not known) inside of a directory using the msbuild copy task?

Answer (score 2):

First [list the directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657684/creating-a-list-of-folders-in-an-itemgroup-using-msbuild) to copy to, then copy the file to each of them using [item batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171474.aspx).

```
<!--declare the source file and target directories somewhere-->
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyTargetDir>c:\temp</MyTargetDir>
  <MySourceFile>c:\somefile</MySourceFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyToSubDirs">
  <!--list dirs-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <TargetDirs Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(`$(MyTargetDir)`))"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!--copy to each dir-->
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(MySourceFile)" DestinationFolder="%(TargetDirs.Identity)"/>
</Target>
```